# Open file with Esperanto characters `Ĝ` and `ĝ` in gVim

Tags: unicode

I have an Autohotkey script to write Esperanto characters. It has the form

```
AppsKey & G::
    if GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
        send Ĝ

    else
    send ĝ
return
```

Notepad has no problem with opening it in a way that shows both `Ĝ` and `ĝ`. On the other hand Vim can't display them.

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166652/how-to-view-utf-8-characters-in-vim-or-gvim
I added to my _vimrc:

```
set enc=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf8,prc
set guifont=Monaco:h11
set guifontwide=NSimsun:h12
```

Vim still doesn't display the character correctly. What do I have to do to get Vim to open the file properly?

Comment: Monaco is a OSX font − are you sure it's installed on your Windows machine? If I use `set guifont=Consolas` it seems to work (but the default font Gvim chooses doesn't!) Also, what exactly do you see? A question mark? Or a black block? Or something else?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Thank you, changing the font to Consolas fixed my issue.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, why not move that comment into an answer? ;)